# reducer stuck at 70%

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am putting together a very initial programming task with hadoop and going with the classic wordcount problem.

Have put a sample file on hdfs, and tried to run wordcount on it. The mapper goes through just fine, however, the reducer is stuck at 70%, never moving forward.

I tried this with files on local file system too, and got  same behaviour.

What could i be doing wrong ?
here are map and reduce functions -

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
        OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
        throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String line = value.toString();

    String[] lineparts = line.split(",");

    for(int i=0; i<lineparts.length; ++i)
    {
        output.collect(new Text(lineparts[i]), new IntWritable(1));
    }


public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values,
              OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
            throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int count = 0;
        while(values.hasNext())
        {
            count=count+1;
        }
        output.collect(key , new IntWritable(count));
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never call `next()` on your iterator, so you're basically creating an infinite loop.

---

As a side note, the preferred way to implement this word count example is not to increment the count by `1`, but use the value instead:

```
IntWritable value = values.next();
count += value.get();
```

This way, you can reuse your `Reducer` as a `Combiner` so that it will compute partial counts for each mapper and emit ("wordX", 7) to the reducer instead of 7 occurrences of ("wordX", 1) from a given mapper. You can read more about combiners [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/map_reduce/map_reduce_combiners.htm).